# Avoid shift of div on jQuery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have several squares place next to one another. On hover, I want the squares to simply increase in width and ( come above the next div) instead of shifting all the squares on its left. I'm using jQuery for this:

```
$('.' + c).hover(//'c' is my variable class :`.alpha1` / `.alpha2` / `.alpha3`
    function () {$(this).animate({height:"30%"},500);},
    function () {$(this).animate({height:"22.2287%"},500);});//original height
```

It is working perfectly but shifting the boxes. On removing the hover, all the squares reset themselves to original state.

My CSS `.boxes` class:

```
.boxes,.alpha1 ,.alpha2, .alpha3{
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:6.36896%;
    height:22.2287%;
    margin:2px;
    box-shadow:0 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;
}
```

**EDIT #1**
[My jsiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/prateeksachan/56yeQ/4/)
Click on the Event links to activate hover effect.

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net to show your problem.

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan It would definitely speed up the resolution of this problem. You may want to look at storing the divs in an absolute position and place them accordingly, since you're already using JavaScript to handle these events, you can use it further to figure out how to align them as well.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prateeksachan/56yeQ/4/
You'll have to click on the `event` links to activate the effect.

Comment: @Duniyadnd: Please see my edited question and the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/prateeksachan/56yeQ/4/

Comment: The best way I can think of to do this would be to add an element inside each of your boxes that is positioned absolutely. Expanding this instead of your actual box will ensure the layout of the box's siblings is not affected.

Comment: @Asad: I tried it . It works, but the visual is not good. It still looks as if there was a parent.

Comment: @xan That is a CSS issue. It should be possible to style it so that it is virtually unnoticeable.

Comment: @Asad: Yes. I did it. I was just informing you.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your floating divs add another div like this:

```
<div class="boxes event1">
   <div class="child">1</div>
 </div>
```

with the following styling:

```
.boxes .child {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 100px;
}
.boxes {
  //all your styling plus:
  overflow: visible;
}
```

and the `hover` event listener should be added on the `.child` div. When you hover it extend the height. In this way you won't see shifting. Of course don't miss the colors and styling of the `.child` div since that's the one you'll be seeing.

Let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: Ya. I tried it. But I'll have to edit the CSS. I can still see the parent behind it.

Comment: put some colours there so you don't see it :)